# Changing scale legend label after creation in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a function like this one:

```
library(tidyverse)
#autoplotter
scatterplot = function(data, x, y, z) {
  ggplot(data, aes(!!as.symbol(x), !!as.symbol(y), color = !!as.symbol(z))) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_gradient2(low = "blue", 
                         high = "red", 
                         mid = "white", 
                         midpoint = 0, 
                         limit = c(-1, 1), 
                         space = "Lab", 
                         name = "Default label")
}
```

We can then call it on some data:

```
#default
mpg %>% 
  mutate(z = runif(n(), min = -1, max = 1)) %>% 
  scatterplot("displ", "cyl", "z")
```

[image]

But what if we want another label for the color scale without changing the gradient settings? One cannot just use `labs()`:

```
mpg %>% 
  mutate(z = runif(n(), min = -1, max = 1)) %>% 
  scatterplot("displ", "cyl", "z") +
  labs(color = "new label")
```

This does not change anything since `labs()` apparently cannot override the `scale_color_gradient2()` in the function.

We can overwrite the scale, but this resets the color scheme:

```
mpg %>% 
  mutate(z = runif(n(), min = -1, max = 1)) %>% 
  scatterplot("displ", "cyl", "z") +
  scale_color_gradient2("new label")
```

[image]

I feel like this should be possible, either by specifying that ggplot2 should only update the `label` parameter, or by using `ggplot2::ggplot_build()` to directly change the `label` parameter only, and then rebuild the plot. However I can't find the label value for the color scale in the object. Too hard to search, but it should be there somewhere!

Comment: why don't you just put an extra argument to your `scatterplot` function?

Comment: In some cases, the function is part of a package, so changing its definition is not so practical.

Comment: Did you downvote my answer? Why?

Comment: Yes. It does not address the question which is specifically about modifying objects in place, not changing the function. StupidWolf provided a correct answer.

Comment: I think that is unfair from your side. My answer gives a valid option to what you were looking for. You have not made the question clear enough in my opinion and also could have commented on your downvote in order to give me a chance  to change my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `guides` and `guide_colourbar` :

```
p <- mpg %>% 
  mutate(z = runif(n(), min = -1, max = 1)) %>% 
  scatterplot("displ", "cyl", "z")
p + guides(color=guide_colorbar(title="new label"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to add an extra argument to your scatterplot function, namely `...`
If you don't add name, your legend name will default to you color variable name.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#autoplotter
scatterplot = function(data, x, y, z, ...) {
  ggplot(data, aes(!!as.symbol(x), !!as.symbol(y), color = !!as.symbol(z))) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_gradient2(low = "blue", 
                          high = "red", 
                          mid = "white", 
                          midpoint = 0, 
                          limit = c(-1, 1), 
                          space = "Lab", ...) #note those three guys here
}

mpg %>% 
  mutate(z = runif(n(), min = -1, max = 1)) %>% 
  scatterplot("displ", "cyl", "z")
```

[image]

```r
mpg %>% 
  mutate(z = runif(n(), min = -1, max = 1)) %>% 
  scatterplot("displ", "cyl", "z", name = 'new_label')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>